# How to find this element in a Cucumber test

Tags: cucumber, watir

In a cucumber test I need to select an href on my page, one which doesn't have an id attribute. The portion of the DOM I'm interested in looks like so:

```
<div id="MyTabs">
    <h1 id="PageName">
        My Items
    </h1>
    <ul class="Tabs">
        <li class="pageTab  on">
            <a href="/the/History.aspx">History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pageTab ">
            <a href="/the/Favorites">Favorites</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pageTab ">
            <a href="/the/Details">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pageTab ">
            <a href="/the/Preferences">Preferences</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to get the link element pertaining to 'Preferences' but am not sure how best to get it via `link(:how_do_I_get_this_stuff`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what is unique about the link. However, based on the html provided, the following might work.

Get the link based on the text:

```
browser.link(:text => 'Preferences').exists?
```

Get the link based on the href attribute:

```
browser.link(:href => /the\/Preferences/).exists?
```

If there are multiple links with text Preferences, you could scope the search to the specific div, which should be unique as it has an id:

```
browser.div(:id => 'MyTabs').link(:text => 'Preferences').exists?
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  Is there a way to query / drill down based on CSS classes?  So for instance, if the parent div had a class of "divclass", while the href has the pageClass...I don't need it in this instance but I can think of scenarios where I might.

Comment: Yes, you can locate the div using any of the locators (eg class). For example, `browser.div(:class => 'divclass').link(:class => 'pageClass')`. For your html sample, you could have done `browser.div(:id => 'MyTabs').ul(class => 'Tabs').li(:class => 'pageTab', :text => 'Preferences')`. However, to reduce brittleness, you should try to use as few locators as possible.